# Conditional operator returning undefined in render method

Tags: reactjs, ternary-operator

I've added some piece of code in render method of react using conditional (ternary) operator. The thing is the condition is rendered true also the control goes into the block. But when I print the value the variable is `undefined`

I tried inserting an alert inside the block to check if the control traverses the block and it worked.

```
const comments =
      details.comments_count >= 1
        ? Object.keys(details.comments_list).forEach(keys => {           
            return (
              <ListItem
                alignItems="flex-start"
                key={details.comments_list[keys].aid}
              >
                <ListItemAvatar>
                  <Avatar>{details.comments_list[keys].aname.charAt(0)}</Avatar>
                </ListItemAvatar>
                <Card style={useStyles.card}>
                  <CardContent>
                    <ListItemText
                      primary={details.comments_list[keys].aname}
                      secondary={details.comments_list[keys].content}
                    />
                  </CardContent>
                </Card>
              </ListItem>
            );
          })
        : null;

console.log(comments);
//=>undefined
```

I don't actually know why this this is happening, given the result of conditional expression is `true`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` returns `undefined`. So you get exactly what you implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` won't return anything but [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). You need to use `map`.

```
const comments =
      details.comments_count >= 1
        ? Object.keys(details.comments_list).map(keys => {           
            return (
              <ListItem
                alignItems="flex-start"
                key={details.comments_list[keys].aid}
              >
                <ListItemAvatar>
                  <Avatar>{details.comments_list[keys].aname.charAt(0)}</Avatar>
                </ListItemAvatar>
                <Card style={useStyles.card}>
                  <CardContent>
                    <ListItemText
                      primary={details.comments_list[keys].aname}
                      secondary={details.comments_list[keys].content}
                    />
                  </CardContent>
                </Card>
              </ListItem>
            );
          })
        : null;

console.log(comments);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, never knew `forEach` returns `undefined`. Thanks @ravibagul91